# How to make my Provisioned Capacity Lambdas properly scale down/in?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework, provisioning, aws-auto-scaling

I have a number of Lambdas that are running with provisioned concurrency. They scale up properly when users are hitting our site, and everything works great there. Unfortunately, at night when nobody is hitting our site, it's not scaling back down. Our AWS bill is now a good $1-2k higher than it should be.

Here's what I see in the Cloudwatch Alarms when there are no users on the site. Specifically, it says `Insufficient Data` beside the alarm that should be scaling the provisioned concurrency down.

[image]

**How do I configure my Cloudwatch AutoScaling alarms so that they scale down properly?** There are no requests on the site at all.

I also recorded this [Loom video](https://www.loom.com/share/ee86e12f98a54033843c4e2e5a6903cb), in case that helps.

Here's my Serverless.yml configuration that I'm using to create the Lambda (using the [serverless-provisioned-concurrency-autoscaling](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-provisioned-concurrency-autoscaling) plugin):

```
  home_page:
    handler: homePage/home_page_handler.get
    memorySize: 3072 # This is high just to speed up page load times
    events:
      - http:
          path: homePage
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: ${file(system/restAPI/function_authorizer.yml)}
    layers:
      - ${cf:layers-${opt:stage}.CommonLibsLambdaLayerExport}
    package:
      patterns:
        - reports/**
    provisionedConcurrency: 1
    concurrencyAutoscaling: true
```

Halp!

Comment: How about including the AWS Application Autoscaling configuration in your question? I'm not going to watch your video. A [requirement of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is that you include all relevant information **in the question itself**.

Comment: @MarkB The video is superfluous information. The autoscaling cloudformation configuration is produced by the Serverless framework (specifically the plugin that I linked) by adding the last 2 lines of my serverless configuration.

Comment: The autoscaling is produce by the framework, just like the CloudWatch alarms are produced by the framework. Yet you included the alarms configuration in your question (via screenshots) but not the autoscaling configuration.

Comment: Can I see the autoscaling configuration in the AWS console? I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: It should show up under the "AWS Application Autoscaling Service" in the console.

Comment: @MarkB I don't see anything useful in there: https://www.loom.com/share/95b9be1bb7734a7d9323c924923d5e27

Comment: @RyanShillington
i strongly recommend to use min/max for `concurrencyAutoscaling` to avoid too high provisioned concurrency (like thousands due to some DDoS)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured this out. Provisioned Concurrency alarms have a setting on what to do when there is "Insufficient data" (i.e. no data).

There's a setting way down on the metric (open the `Advanced Configuration` section).

I had this set to `Treat missing data as missing` and this needs to be set to `Treat missing data as bad (breaching threshold)` for the Lambda Provisioned concurrency to be scaled down when there are no users.

[image]

In my case, I've [opened up a ticket with the serverless-provisioned-concurrency-autoscaling plugin](https://github.com/neiman-marcus/serverless-provisioned-concurrency-autoscaling/issues/36) to get this fixed, since I don't control it myself.